# How to get just TypeScript types from threeJs package?

Tags: typescript, webpack, three.js

I'm building a front-end with Webpack that includes threeJs functionality. In the past, I used to NOT include threeJs in my bundle to keep it small (I used the threeJs UMD from a CDN link in my index.html). I did however use the `@types/three` package for typing.

However, `@types/three` has now been deprecated. Instead, `three` now includes its own moduled types. But now, I can't figure out how to use the three package just for its types without also including ALL of the massive threeJs code in my bundle.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was initially deprecated, but [`@types/three`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/three) is now the place to use again. [Moving back to DefinitivelyTyped](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/21174) was done in Jan 2021.

So just add types by running

```js
npm install -D @types/three
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Things have changed over time and the below solution is not longer necessary, check the new [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67264247/1887860) for an easier approach. Leaving the original answer for posterity.

### Old answer

My suggestion, since you are using Webpack, is to:

1. add `three` as project dependency so you can continue developing normally and leverage the included types, then
2. exclude it from begin bundled with your app by using Webpack [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

`externals` prevents bundling of certain `import`ed packages and instead retrieves them at runtime.

Following the same steps of the documentation example, you would end up with a setup similar to the following:

**index.html**

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r106/three.min.js">
</script>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    three: 'three'
  }
};
```

This leaves any dependent modules on `three` unchanged, i.e. the code shown below will still work:

```
import { Scene } from 'three';

const scene = new Scene();
```

Comment: Ah, yes -- good thinking on externals! This worked, though it was tricky getting to import typed OrbitalControls from the same npm package without also including the main ThreeJs build. I found a way around that problem by copying over everything in the `node_modules/three/examples/jsm/*` dir to my code base and altering their import paths. You can see my solution [here](https://github.com/MagnusBrzenk/threejs-typescript-boilerplate/tree/001-deployToGithub)